# DKIM - configuration question - HOW?

Tags: civimail, wordpress

I'm trying to setup DKIM. Where does the private key get input?  I've searched docs, and not finding anything.  Using my hosting companies mail().

All good on SPF setup, creating keys, setting in DNS, but... can't find where to put the DKIM private key.

Thanks in advance!

Clark Hodge -
Chase the Music

Answer (score 5):

You probably have to ask your hosting provider to do this.

CiviCRM doesn't have an interface to provide DKIM keys; OpenDKIM runs as a separate process alongside the MTA on your hosting environment.

Your key will most likely end up in `/etc/opendkim`, but that really depends on your hosting environment. [DigitalOcean have a pretty straightforward DKIM HOWTO for Debian](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy), if you have control of your server.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  I'll shoot the request upstream to my hosting company.  Really appreciate the answer, and the extra tidbits - to make it easy for the host guy/gal.